# Traveling from Hartford to JFK Friday and back on Sunday Afternoon

Tags: amtrak

I’m going from Hartford to JFK this Friday and coming back on Sunday leaving JFK at 2pm. I’m thinking of taking Amtrak rather than driving as I usually do. Will the train system be reliable on Sund
ay in the snow?

Answer (score 3):

You may have trouble returning home via train.

[Amtrak's current service advisories](https://www.amtrak.com/service-alerts-and-notices) state that the northbound trains will terminate at New Haven, CT on Sunday.

> Modified service for Sunday, January 20, includes:
>
> [Northeast Regional](https://www.amtrak.com/content/dam/projects/dotcom/english/public/documents/timetables/Northeast-Schedule-W04-111218.pdf) service (Boston – New York – Washington, D.C.): Trains 160,164, 88,161,135,167 will not operate between New York and Boston.
>
> [Vermonter](https://www.amtrak.com/content/dam/projects/dotcom/english/public/documents/timetables/Vermonter-Schedule-P55-060918.pdf) (St. Albans, Vt. – New York – Washington, D.C.): Trains 54, 57 will not operate between St. Albans, Vt. and New Haven, Conn.

So much for the Vermonter.

The Northeast Corridor trains 140 and 132, the late Sunday trains, are not currently listed as affected, so you may be able to take one of those. But you should expect them to be a bit crowded...

Comment: But the Vermonter is not the only Amtrak service from New York to Hartford; there are a number of Northeast Regional trains as well, including weekend service.  Train 140, for example, does not seem to be cancelled or curtailed.  Additionally, one can take Amtrak or Metro-North to New Haven and connect to the [Hartford Line](http://www.hartfordline.com/).

Comment: @NateEldredge Hm, good catch. As far as Amtrak goes, train 140 is all that isn't currently affected. Even if it does end up running, it'll proably be more crowded than usual. I'm not sure it will, though; we're expecting a very significant snowstorm. As for other transit systems, I didn't mention them because he didn't ask.

Comment: @NateEldredge As far as I can see, the CTrail trains are still scheduled, so taking MNR to New Haven and then the Hartford Line is probably going to be the best way to get back on this day.